# Which metric should I trust to evaluate my predictive model

Tags: predictive-models, prediction, scikit-learn, unbalanced-classes, mathematical-statistics

I am working on predictive model and when I evaluate it, I find good `accuracy_score`, `precision_score`, `recall_score`, and `f1_score`. But I don't get good results using confusion matrix.

What is the metric that should I Trust ?

```
accuracy_score:  0.987727165447
confusion_matrix: [[338961   3857 ]
                   [   252     27  ]]
precision_score: 0.998449790932
recall_score:    0.987727165447
f1_score:        0.993031083087
```

I am using Scikit-Learn metrics.

```
‘precision’ sklearn.metrics.precision_score
‘recall’    sklearn.metrics.recall_score
‘f1’        sklearn.metrics.f1_score
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you have highly unbalanced classes. If 99% of the data have y = 0, to get high accuracy, all you have to do is predict y = 0 regardless of the features in the data set. This shows that your model is accurate only because the classes are so highly unbalanced, but it is not good at actually differentiating between the two classes. None of the statistics are best, they just tell you different things about your model's fit.

A metric like AUC, Gini or KS would be better for comparing models and evaluating model fit when you have highly unbalanced classes. These statistics rank order the predictions and remove the effect of unbalanced classes. Even with an unbalanced sample, if you predict y = 0 for all of your data, you will get AUC = 0.5. Keep in mind that you also want to use a hold out sample for these evaluation metrics.

For AUC details, check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic or http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.auc.html for implementation in Python.

Comment: One more question, What are the techniques to balance the classes. I used two approaches to balance the data [1-weight function with SVM, and 2- KNN to predict based on the neighbors' results] Can you recommend anyother approaches ?

Comment: You can sample from your data set to obtain a balanced sample or penalize the model for missclassifying the minority class. Interesting article here: http://statistics.berkeley.edu/sites/default/files/tech-reports/666.pdf.

Comment: Yes, Thanks a lot, I was waiting the results as it's taking time. Just one more question, I found AUC varying between 0.7 and 0.8. Is this good sign, Can you give me an interval to say that my predictive model is acceptable, good, great.